# Direcline bot channel - How to change the botAvatarImage image background and initial background color

Tags: styles, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Is there any styling options available to change the background-color of **botAvatarImage** / **botAvatarInitials** which we are using in our Directline bot channel. ?

Also, i need to remove the borders for the **botAvatarImage**.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is one option to change the background.

```
styleOptions: {
    botAvatarBackgroundColor: "transparent",
    botAvatarImage: 'YOUR URL',
}
```

I don't think it has a border by default but you could try override the css with these classess

`.webchat__defaultAvatar .webchat__imageAvatar__image`

You could find the entire list of style options in here [defaultStyleOptions.js](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js)